# GDAL error when trying to enable PostGIS on PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, gdal

In order to enable geographical data on my Django project, I am trying to enable the GeoDjango extensions on my Ubuntu 16.04 box.

PostGIS and GDAL are required obviously and do not seem to play well together.
From the psql shell, when running the following command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/rtpostgis-2.2.so": /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

This error seems familiar among Django and Python users, and solutions evocate fixing the virtualenv. But this case is purely from the database, there is no Python involved. `sqlite3` version conflicts seems a common pitfall too, even if I am not able to trace such issue in this case.

Also, I have checked if the library file has the symbols, and it seeps that it is the case:

```
nm -D /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1 | grep sqlite3_column
                 U sqlite3_column_blob
                 U sqlite3_column_bytes
                 U sqlite3_column_count
                 U sqlite3_column_decltype
                 U sqlite3_column_double
                 U sqlite3_column_int
                 U sqlite3_column_int64
                 U sqlite3_column_name
                 U sqlite3_column_table_name
                 U sqlite3_column_text
                 U sqlite3_column_type
```

The sqlite3_column_table_name symbol is found in the library and the error message says the opposite.

How can I fix my environment to get PostGIS running?

Comment: I get the same error on Ubuntu 14.4.Did you come up with any solutions? @David G.